# Efficient way to filter one data frame by ranges in another

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have a data frame containing a bunch of data and a date/time column indicating when each data point was collected. I have another data frame that lists time spans, where a "Start" column indicates the date/time when each span starts and an "End" column indicates the date/time when each span ends.

I've created a dummy example below using simplified data:

```
main_data = data.frame(Day=c(1:30))

spans_to_filter = 
    data.frame(Span_number = c(1:6),
               Start = c(2,7,1,15,12,23),
               End = c(5,10,4,18,15,26))
```

I toyed around with a few ways of solving this problem and ended up with the following solution:

```
require(dplyr)    
filtered.main_data =
    main_data %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(present = any(Day >= spans_to_filter$Start & Day <= spans_to_filter$End)) %>% 
    filter(present) %>% 
    data.frame()
```

This works perfectly fine, but I noticed it can take a while to process if I have a lot of data (I assume because I'm performing a row-wise comparison). I'm still learning the ins-and-outs of R and I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of performing this operation, preferably using dplyr/tidyr?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a function that you can run in `dplyr` to find dates within a given range using the `between` function (from `dplyr`). For each value of `Day`, `mapply` runs `between` on each of the pairs of `Start` and `End` dates and the function uses `rowSums` to return `TRUE` if `Day` is between at least one of them. I'm not sure if it's the most efficient approach, but it results in nearly a factor of four improvement in speed.

```
test.overlap = function(vals) {
  rowSums(mapply(function(a,b) between(vals, a, b), 
                 spans_to_filter$Start, spans_to_filter$End)) > 0
}

main_data %>% 
  filter(test.overlap(Day))
```

If you're working with dates (rather than with date-times), it may be even more efficient to create a vector of specific dates and test for membership (this might be a better approach even with date-times):

```
filt.vals = as.vector(apply(spans_to_filter, 1, function(a) a["Start"]:a["End"]))

main_data %>% 
  filter(Day %in% filt.vals)
```

Now compare execution speeds. I shortened your code to require only the filtering operation:

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  OP=main_data %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    filter(any(Day >= spans_to_filter$Start & Day <= spans_to_filter$End)),
  eipi10 = main_data %>% 
    filter(test.overlap(Day)),
  eipi10_2 = main_data %>% 
    filter(Day %in% filt.vals)
  )

Unit: microseconds
     expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval cld
       OP 2496.019 2618.994 2875.0402 2701.8810 2954.774 4741.481   100   c
   eipi10  658.941  686.933  782.8840  714.4440  770.679 2474.941   100  b 
 eipi10_2  579.338  601.355  655.1451  619.2595  672.535 1032.145   100 a
```

**UPDATE:** Below is a test with a much larger data frame and a few extra date ranges to match (thanks to @Frank for suggesting this in his now-deleted comment). It turns out that the speed gains are far greater in this case (about a factor of 200 for the `mapply/between` method, and far greater still for the second method).

```
main_data = data.frame(Day=c(1:100000))

spans_to_filter = 
  data.frame(Span_number = c(1:9),
             Start = c(2,7,1,15,12,23,90,9000,50000),
             End = c(5,10,4,18,15,26,100,9100,50100))

microbenchmark(
  OP=main_data %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    filter(any(Day >= spans_to_filter$Start & Day <= spans_to_filter$End)),
  eipi10 = main_data %>% 
    filter(test.overlap(Day)),
  eipi10_2 = {
    filt.vals = unlist(apply(spans_to_filter, 1, function(a) a["Start"]:a["End"]))
    main_data %>% 
      filter(Day %in% filt.vals)}, 
  times=10
  )

Unit: milliseconds
     expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq         max neval cld
       OP 5130.903866 5137.847177 5201.989501 5216.840039 5246.961077 5276.856648    10   b
   eipi10   24.209111   25.434856   29.526571   26.455813   32.051920   48.277326    10  a 
 eipi10_2    2.505509    2.618668    4.037414    2.892234    6.222845    8.266612    10  a
```

Answer (score 16):

In the data.table package starting from v1.9.8, *non-equi* joins has been implemented. With this, I've created a wrapper function `inrange()` for exactly these kind of operations, where the task involves finding if a point lies in any of the intervals provided, and if so return `TRUE`, else `FALSE`.

```
require(data.table) # v>=1.9.8
setDT(main_data)[Day %inrange% spans_to_filter[, 2:3]] # inclusive bounds
#     Day
#  1:   1
#  2:   2
#  3:   3
#  4:   4
#  5:   5
#  6:   7
#  7:   8
#  8:   9
#  9:  10
# 10:  12
# 11:  13
# 12:  14
# 13:  15
# 14:  16
# 15:  17
# 16:  18
# 17:  23
# 18:  24
# 19:  25
# 20:  26
```

See `?inrange` for more.

Comment: This becomes way faster than the accepted answer as the lookup table grows.

Comment: Improvements were made recently.. should be faster on smaller lookup tables as well.

Answer (score 2):

Using Base R:

```
main_data[unlist(lapply(main_data$Day, 
  function(x) any(x >= spans_to_filter$Start & x <= spans_to_filter$End))),]
```