# Subsetting data frame with multiple date conditions for ranges in between

Tags: r, date

I need subsets between multiple dates.
Example data frame:

```
testdf <- data.frame(short_date = seq(as.Date("2007-03-01"), 
                                  as.Date("2008-09-01"), by = 'day'))
```

An example of data frame with values for date ranges:

```
dates_cut <- structure(list(emergence = structure(c(13627, 13997), class = "Date"), disease_onset = structure(c(13694, 14062), class = "Date")), .Names = c("emergence", "disease_onset"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Obviously this is just a sample, there is a number of years for which I need subsets of data in between (`$emergence date` and `$disese_onset`).
This works for one data range:

```
testdf %>% filter(short_date >=dates_cut[1,1], short_date >=dates_cut[1,2])
```

The problem is when there are multiple date ranges.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454565/efficient-way-to-filter-one-data-frame-by-ranges-in-another

Comment: thanks Lamia, should have looked better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to `lapply` over the rows of `dates_cut` and then store each subset in a list. After that you can `rbind` them all together with `do.call`:

```
list <- lapply(1:nrow(dates_cut), function(i) {
              testdf[which(testdf$short_date >= dates_cut[i, "emergence"] &
              testdf$short_date <= dates_cut[i, "disease_onset"]), , drop = FALSE]})

res <- do.call(rbind, list)

head(res)
#   short_date
#55 2007-04-24
#56 2007-04-25
#57 2007-04-26
#58 2007-04-27
#59 2007-04-28
#60 2007-04-29
```

Comment: thanks, I have already found solution thanks to comment on my question, should have looked better, but your solution seems ok, as well.