# Filtering one dataframe by a multiple columns in another

Tags: r, dplyr

Sorry if this is a silly question!

My aim is basically the same as this post here: [Take dates from one dataframe and filter data in another dataframe - R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454565/efficient-way-to-filter-one-data-frame-by-ranges-in-another) and continue using dplr as I am later going to run this code across all rows of my dataset using row_wise()

However, in my case I wish to take the 'start' and 'end' years from 2 different columns in the second dataframe.

Here's some dummy data (taken from the original post and adapted to my problem):

```
main_data = data.frame(year=c(1966:2017))

second_data = data.frame(Participant = c(1:6),
           Start_year = c(2012,1994,1974,1983,1969,2002),
           End_year = c(2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017))
```

and wrote this code based on the original post:

```
filtered.total =
   main_data %>% 
   rowwise() %>% 
   mutate(year = any(year >= second_data$Start_year & year <= 
      second_data$End_year)) %>%
   filter(year) %>%
   data.frame()
```

I'm also filtering my data by location(country and county)but it just gives me the following error message for my dataset:

```
Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : Result must have length 2299, not 0
```

and for the dummy data above:

```
 In year <= second_data$End_year :
 longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Thanks for any help - quite new to R and my PhD is testing my minimal knowledge right now!

Comment: Your code is not throwing any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might need to use `min(second_data$year)` and `max(second_data$year)`, as at the moment you're providing many values to compare against, and i think its complaining about that.