# Filter between multiple date ranges

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, filtering, lubridate

I have a large dataframe with four measurments per second over two weeks. Hence the dataframe is quite large.
I also have two vectors with start and end dates, which define certain time ranges within the dataframe and which I have to filter out.
What I want to do is to extract the data between the start and end dates.
My data looks something like this.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(datetime = seq(ymd_hms("2020/01/01 00:00:00"),
                                by = "sec",
                                length.out = 3600),
                 var = rnorm(3600))
```

And my start/end vector look like this. Here I only added two start/end combinations. But the actual vector contain more values.

```
start = c(ymd_hms("2020/01/01 00:1:00"), ymd_hms("2020/01/01 00:30:00"))
end = c(ymd_hms("2020/01/01 00:1:04"), ymd_hms("2020/01/01 00:30:04"))
```

I tried to just filter it, using

```
filtered <- df %>%
  filter(datetime >= start & datetime <= end)

head(filtered)

             datetime        var
1 2020-01-01 00:01:00 -0.2245330
2 2020-01-01 00:01:02  0.5926424
3 2020-01-01 00:01:04 -0.3824533
4 2020-01-01 00:30:01 -0.7202059
5 2020-01-01 00:30:03 -0.5775794
```

But it seems to downsample the data, as the filtered dataframe has only three measurments for the first time interval, instead of the expected five values.

If I filter only for the first start and end date, I get the five values.

```
filtered2 <- df %>%
  filter(datetime >= start[1] & datetime <= end[1])

head(filtered2)

             datetime         var
1 2020-01-01 00:01:00 -0.22453305
2 2020-01-01 00:01:01  1.13452854
3 2020-01-01 00:01:02  0.59264239
4 2020-01-01 00:01:03 -0.03700048
5 2020-01-01 00:01:04 -0.38245332
```

Where I get stuck is:
Why does the first filtering work, but does not return the expected full daterange?
And how can I get the complete data filtered?

I alreadz tried `filter(between(datetime, start, end)`. This gave me the expected result, but only for the first daterange. It seeems that `dplyr::between` does not accept vecorts.

Any help would be very welcome.

**UPDATE**
@ekoam has pointed out correctly that `data.table::between` works as well. But as `dplyr::between`, it doesn't like vectors.

Comment: What exactly is the goal? For filtering with vectors, your vectors should have the same length as your `df`.

Comment: @arg0naut91 I have a long time series (millisecond mesurments over two weeks) and I have to disect it according to certain start and end dates. Those dates will change in the future, so I want to keep them in a vector or list and filter my data that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With some inspiration from this question on how to [Efficient way to filter one data frame by ranges in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454565/efficient-way-to-filter-one-data-frame-by-ranges-in-another), I came up with the following solutions.

One is a very slow with very large datasets:
It takes my data provided above and uses `rowwise()`

```
filtered3 <- df %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  filter(any(datetime >= start & datetime <= end))
```

As I mentioned, with more than 3 million rows in my data, this was very slow.

Another option, also from the answer linked above, includes using the data.table package, which has an `inrange` function. This one works much faster.

```
library(data.table)
range <- data.table(start = start, end = end)
filtered4 <- setDT(df)[datetime %inrange% range]
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is

```
df %>% filter(dplyr::between(datetime, start[[1L]], end[[1L]]) | dplyr::between(datetime, start[[2L]], end[[2L]]))
```

**Update**

I did the following checks:

```
res1 <- df %>% filter(data.table::between(datetime, start[[1L]], end[[1L]]) | data.table::between(datetime, start[[2L]], end[[2L]]))

res2 <- df %>% filter(dplyr::between(datetime, start[[1L]], end[[1L]]) | dplyr::between(datetime, start[[2L]], end[[2L]]))

all(res1 == res2)
```

Output

```
> all(res1 == res2)
[1] TRUE
```

So if you are also using `dplyr 1.0.2` and `data.table 1.13.0`, you can use either `dplyr::between` or `data.table::between` for the task.

Comment: Thanks @ekoam . Your answer works for the example data. I should have clairfied, that my actual dataset is a rather long dataset with millisecond measurments over two weeks and therefore my start and end vectors are also more than two values each. Using OR statements would get very long very fast.